# How to pass a ruby script's output as arguments to a shell command using command substitution?

Tags: ruby, escaping, command-substitution

I have the following in a_script.rb:

```
if ARGV.empty?
    puts "string_without_spaces 'string with spaces'"
else
    p ARGV
end
```

When I run:

```
ruby a_script.rb `ruby a_script.rb`
```

I get the following output:

```
["string_without_spaces", "'string", "with", "spaces'"]
```

But instead, I would like to have the following output:

```
["string_without_spaces", "string with spaces"]
```

How do I change the script to get the wanted output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your bash command. Backtick is escaping the `"` and `'`

You can use `xargs`

```
ruby a_script.rb | xargs ruby a_script.rb
```

Comment: I found more convincing details in [this comment](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24954/when-is-xargs-needed#comment33593_24956)